# Conflict between standard BibLatex and Babel

Tags: biblatex, pdftex, babel

The following minimalistic document produces an "Undefined control sequence" error at `\begin{document}`. When I put `\usepackage[english]{babel}`in comments the error disappears. The compilation steps I am doing are pdflatex -> biber -> pdflatex.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic,citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}
hello world
\end{document}
```

For obvious reasons I *really* want references in my document, but I would also like to use babel. I am using MiKTeX 2.9, pdfTeX version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14. Biblatex version is 3.3, and babel is 3.8m. Is there any solution to this conflict of packages?

BibLat

Comment: You can get the versions by placing `\listfiles` at the very top of your document, after a LaTeX run (just force though the errors) you will get a list at the end of your `.log` file with the package versions. It is quite likely that `biblatex` and `babel` are not up to date (I suspect `babel` is too old for your `biblatex`, but I don't know exactly which command TeX complains about). You will need to do an update in User and Amdin mode, see [How should one maintain and update a MiKTeX installation?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108447/35864).

Comment: Thank you! I am looking into updating the packages via MiKTeX at this very moment, although for some strange reason it is saying it cannot find the update manager... I am looking into this :)

Comment: A warm welcome to TeX.SE! I'm not getting that error when I use texlive 2015.  The MWE compiles fine using latexmk, xelatex or lualatex.

Comment: My version of `babel` is `2016/02/09 3.9q`, so I think we can safely say that the problem is with your outdated `babel` version. You will now only have to find a way to do that update.

Comment: You should also load babel before biblatex so that it can pick up the language information.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved by a package update (`babel` was outdated).

Answer (score 2):

As [moewe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/35864/moewe) kindly pointed out, the installations of my packages (and just MiKTeX in general) was older than the observable universe. As such, I have just completely reinstalled MiKTeX -- which I am sure is overkill, but I digress -- and now my package versions are 3.9n for babel (2016/01/08) and v3.3 for biblatex (2016/03/03). That has (almost unsurprisingly) resolved the issues.

Comment: You should run `MiKTeX Update` after re-installation  (latest babel is `3.9.q`) , and redo the formats.