# packages titlepage & biblatex don't work together

Tags: biblatex, titles, koma-script, incompatibility

the following code works well:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[british,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{titlepage}
\begin{document}
\begin{fullsizetitle}
\blindtext[13]
\end{fullsizetitle}
\end{document}
```

and same for this code:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[british,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\begin{document}
    \begin{fullsizetitle}
        \blindtext[13]
    \end{fullsizetitle}
\end{document}
```

but both together

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[british,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{titlepage}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\begin{document}
    \begin{fullsizetitle}
        \blindtext[13]
    \end{fullsizetitle}
\end{document}
```

give the error message:

> ```
> Undefined control sequence. \begin{document}
> ```

Comment: Where do you have the titlepage package from? It is not found on CTAN, making it a bit hard for us to help

Comment: I found this code here at StackExchange
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20177/remove-margins-for-title-page
More information (in German) are given here:
https://komascript.de/titlepage

Comment: The first and the third example work for me with the same result. The second example results in an error because environment `fullsizetitle` is undefined. So your code does not work if you do not load package `titlepage`.

Comment: The problem only occurs if two languages are given to bable.

Comment: Historically version mismatch can be a problem double check your versions see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302800/conflict-between-standard-biblatex-and-babel

Comment: It works for me with two languages given to `babel`, too. But package `titlepage` is needed.

Comment: I installed TeX Live 2019 today. No updates are available....

Comment: See also https://komascript.de/node/2242

Comment: I can not reproduce the error on a fully updated MikTeX system. I downloaded `titlepage-11.tds.zip` from https://komascript.de/node/1213 and unpacked the `tex/latex/titlepage` folder into an empty directory. In that directory I then created a `mwe.tex` with the contents of your last code example. Then I ran LaTeX on that document and got no errors. Everything shows as expected. I added `\listfiles` to the beginning of the file so you can compare versions more easily. You can find my complete `.log` and the `.tex` at https://gist.github.com/moewew/2eb75a9e9fd48ea19b314674d571bd52.

Comment: ... Please run the `.tex` with `\listfiles` and upload the *complete* `.log` file to a text-sharing website such as https://pastebin.com/, https://gist.github.com/, https://hastebin.com/ ...

Comment: I uploaded the log file to:
https://komascript.de/node/2242
Thank you!

Comment: The uploaded `.log` is not complete and (maybe more importantly) it is not the `.log` of the MWE you posted here or on the KOMA-Script forum. Your `.log` loads `scrreprt.cls`, but the MWEs all use `scrbook.cls`. There are a few other differences in load order as well. Please run the shown MWE and upload the `.log` file for the MWE. If the MWE does not reproduce the issue change it so that it does.

Comment: I crosschecked it and indeed: with bable + "english" it works but with bable + "british" ist doesn't work. I changed the original code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This bug is fixed in version 3.13.
>
> Please update your TeX system to obtain current (and matching) versions of `biblatex` and Biber.
>
> The answer below is kept for historical interest and background info.

This is a very elusive bug in `biblatex`. After discussions in https://komascript.de/node/2242, the KOMA-Script developer reported the issue at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/894 and suggested a possible fix that was added to `biblatex` with https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commit/26c2072829d78447a9bb1931bd22662b34a19e18.

The issue is resolved in `biblatex` v3.13.

The bug only occurred if the `biblatex` language module (the `.lbx`) for `<language_1>` inherits from `<language_0>` in a particular way and `<language_0>` is not loaded as a document language. In these cases `biblatex` would add an undefined macro to `\extras<language_0>`. Since `<language_0>` is not loaded, this macro would normally not be used and so this would not cause any issues. But `titlepage` uses `\providecaptionname` which hooks into `\extras<language>` in such a way that the undefined commands caused a problem.

In the specific case of the MWE `british` inherits from `english`, but `english` is not loaded. Still, `biblatex` writes undefined commands to `\extrasenglish` and `\providecaptionname` trips up.

The problem does not occur with `ngerman` because the inheritance setup between `ngerman` and `german` is slightly different, which means that the macros that end up undefined in the `british` case are actually defined here.

Until the version with the fix is released I can offer two workarounds

1. Just load `english` as well as `british`. (Be sure to get the load order/main language right.)
2. Incorporate the suggested fix into your preamble. Note that the fix should be removed from your preamble when a new version of `biblatex` is released. Hence the code block below will produce an error with upcoming `biblatex` releases.

   ```
   \makeatletter
   \@ifpackagelater{biblatex}{2019/05/28}
     {\blx@error
        {'\string\blx@maplang' fix no longer needed. Remove it}
        {Remove the redefinition of '\string\blx@maplang' from your preamble}}
     {\def\blx@maplang#1#2{%
        \csgappto{extras#1}{%
          \blx@resetpunct
          \csuse{abx@extras@#2}%
          \csuse{abx@strings@#2}}%
        \csgappto{noextras#1}{%
          \blx@resetpunct
          \csuse{abx@noextras@#2}}}}
   \makeatother
   ```

Comment: Note that I still get a similar error with `biblatex` 3.14 and `tex4ht` (odt output), which is fixed by the above `\def\blx@maplang#1#2` definition.

Comment: @JSpitzm If you can reproduce the issue with 'normal' LaTeX (`pdflatex`, `xelatex`, `lualatex`) please post this issue with an MWE at the `biblatex` bug tracker. If this only occurs with `tex4ht`, please go to their bugtracker and inform them about this (I seem to remember that they have to patch quite a few LaTeX commands that `biblatex` relies on as well as some internal `biblatex` commands to make sure everything goes as planned).

Comment: I cannot reproduce outside tex4ht. It's probably broken in biblatex.4ht

Comment: @JSpitzm OK. I know next to nothing about `tex4ht`, so the only hint I can add is that we recently changed `\blx@maplang` for `polyglossia` support: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commit/8db14c03546c0f6075c06ecf07089b921ca8b8ca (https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/930) maybe the fact that the definition of `\blx@maplang` now happens in `\AtBeginDocument` poses an issue.

Comment: Yes your guess was right. `biblatex.4ht` (l.224ff.) has some code which executes `\blx@lbxinput` in the preamble. Shifting this to `\AtBeginDocument` seems to work. I'll file a bug report at tex4ht

Comment: Just a quick update: The issue is fixed in today's tex4ht release.